# Getting version of current installed software during upgrade

Tags: wix

During upgrade, I want to retrieve version of the software that already is already installed. After researching a while I implemented this code:

```
<MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." AllowSameVersionUpgrades="yes" />
<Upgrade Id="$(var.UpgradeCode)">
  <UpgradeVersion Minimum="10.0.0.0" Maximum="$(var.VersionNumber)" OnlyDetect="yes" Property="DETECTED_VERSION" />
</Upgrade>
```

During upgrade, in custom action, when I read `DETECTED_VERSION` property it contains guid (probably product id). Is there a way to get the actual version?

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to add code to call MsiGetProductInfo(Product guid....INSTALLPROPERTY_VERSIONSTRING) or scripting/interop equivalent and show it on your upgrade dialog form. I'm not aware of any Windows Installer property or WiX support that provides this.

You might have an issue if retrieving this requires elevated privileges because early UI sequences are not elevated by default.